# Scrolling back up with timer

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I created a chat application. When ever I add something to textbox and click on enter text add to the databinder and scroll bar goes up. I used a javascript to scroll down on click which is working fine but due to timer, the scroll bar is moving back to top the soon its dragged down. My code follows

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#kdiv1
{
    position:relative;
    left:300px;
    top:20px;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#kdiv2
{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    left:300px;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function scrooldown(div) {
        var scrollDiv = document.getElementById(div);
        scrollDiv.scrollTop = scrollDiv.scrollHeight;
        scrollDiv = null;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" defaultfocus="text">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">

        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" RenderMode="Block">
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="kdiv1">
           <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <span>
             <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Message") %> <br />
            </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
            <div id="kdiv2">
            <asp:TextBox ID="text" runat="server"/>
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" onclick="button1_Click" OnClientClick="scrooldown('kdiv1')" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# code

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=chatserver;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=********;" + "OPTION=3";
        OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
        try
        {
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO shoutbox(name, message)VALUES(?, ?)", MyConnection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = "something";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.Text).Value = text.Text;
            MyConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        try
        {
            MyConnection.Open();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select message from shoutbox", MyConnection);
            OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string ep = dr[0].ToString();
                values.Add(new PositionData(ep));
            }
            Repeater1.DataSource = values;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
            text.Text = "";
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somebody retag this with C# - I don't have the privs, thanks.

Comment: @jimbojw - I don't think C# has a role in my issue. My error is client side error for clear understanding I added my C# code but in fact that will not fix my error.

Comment: It very well may be a client-side issue, but I think you'll have better luck finding an answer by tagging it with all appropriate labels.  As soon as you start talking about "databinder" my eyes glaze over because I don't know what that does. :)

Comment: don't worry jimbojw, many .net programmers don't know the difference between the client and server anyway.

Comment: @jimbojw - hehehe I learnt using it just a week back. I just used it to add text just like `labels` but plus point is it can be used along with repeaters to repeat values.

Comment: @Diodeus agreed. And MS doesn't make it any easier by allowing the definition of handlers in C# (which it somehow magically turns into JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

You will get a better result if you move the div `kdiv1` around the `UpdatePanel` instead of inside:

```
<div id="kdiv1">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" RenderMode="Block">
        ...
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The problem with the current situation is that the div `kdiv1` itself will be replaced after each partial postback, and all its state (like scroll positions) will be lost.

However, even after this change, you would still have the problem that the line(s) that are added after the partial postback will not be within the visible area, because these new lines will be added after the last call to `scrolldown('kdiv1')`.

To solve this, you could register a function to be called every time a partial postback happened. You do this by adding the following javascript to the header of the page:

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(sender, args) {
            scrolldown('kdiv1');
        });
    };
</script>
```

**Note: In my examples I wrote "scrolldown" instead of "scrooldown", since I assume this is a typo.**

Comment: @Kars - I updated my response to be more specific about the `window.onload` code.